# How to access the ajax submitted data in PHP from javascript FormData

Tags: javascript, php, multipartform-data

I have the following code to upload a file along with a user_id and a token via ajax post:

**HTML Form:**

```
<?php foreach($model['all_documents'] as $doc=>$val){ ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?=$model['user_id']?>" />
  <button type="button" class="col-md-7 btn btn-default documentUpload form-control">
    <i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i> انتخاب اسکن
  </button>
  <input type="file" name="<?=$doc?>" class="documentUpload" style="display: none;" />
  <button class="col-md-4 btn btn-primary form-control submit pull-left">
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> آپلود
  </button>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".form").submit(function(){
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  console.info(formData); // Shows FormData(), but can't find my stuff in it

  $.ajax({
    url: '<?=Yii::$app->homeUrl?>courier/upload-document',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    // beforeSend: function(){
    // },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

I tried to access the user_id and file like:

```
// $user_id = $_POST['user_id']; // Nothing
// $docs = $_FILES['image_url']; // Nothing
print_r($_POST);exit;
```

What I get in my chrome's network response is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundaryk0378isAjf4Png8L
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "_csrf"

dy5nWlJFb1U6dwg.FwshCjZ5NANmd1tkFFcdFh8sLgcnQQQxZzwoOA==
------WebKitFormBoundaryk0378isAjf4Png8L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_id"

456
------WebKitFormBoundaryk0378isAjf4Png8L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_url"; filename="avatar3.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG


IHDR����4�PLTE�ɦ!!!�e<"""���r=-�Y<����cB   �����`@��^?����G2�ȥ�R8u>-�K4�aA�[=�D0����Z<�\=�W;�Ƥ�S9�P6�N6����ma�ġ��������Ÿ_>���UF<�Y<��������U:����ͭޏh纥�y@.|B/���ի��I3�~V�jA��ϻ�������Ѵ�m[����oG�L5Ɵ����쩅.,
```

Comment: Show your html form too.. `.form` means the form class attribute is called `form`. Are you sure you don't mean `form.submit(function()` instead???

Comment: @Akintunde I updated the question!

Comment: Can you print straight from the html source??  Need to know the variable outcome.. Remove `async=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Setting `processData` to false lets you prevent jQuery from
   automatically transforming the data into a query string.
2. Setting the `contentType` to false is imperative, since otherwise
       jQuery will set it incorrectly.

Comment: I also needed to set `cache: false,`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
```

or

```
var formData = $(".form").serializeArray();
```

or

```
var formData = $(".form").serialize();
```

So that your code would look like this:

```
$(".form").submit(function(){
  var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
  console.log(formData);

  $.ajax({
    url: '<?=Yii::$app->homeUrl?>courier/upload-document',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    // beforeSend: function(){
    // },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Next in your PHP code try checking whether these things work as you did.

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$docs = $_FILES['image_url'];
print_r($_POST);
exit;
```

**UPDATED:**

The serialize() method does not send files. 
If you need to upload files with the serialize(), you could either get the base64 value and send it as a string. The serialize() method is supported in even old browsers which does not recognize the formData() API. That is the only advantage of this method.

If you want to use the formData() API in order to upload files, then you may refer this [guide](https://www.zerosack.org/blog/24484189674/What-is-difference-between-serialize()-&-FormData()-methods-in-jQuery.).

Comment: How is this helpful??

Comment: @Akintunde, `formData = $(this).serializeArray();` would create an array with the form data. Also, checks whether the correct data is being sent by using thee `console.log(formData);`.

So, you could verify and easily debug your code.

Comment: Do I get the file along with the input data? using serialize() the file info does not show via the console now.

Comment: @AfghanDeveloper, no it wouldn't. If you want to send a file using the serialize() method, you need to get the base64 value of it. Otherwise you'll have to use the formData() API. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Akintunde, `new FormData(this);` should be used when the file is going to be uploaded. At the moment, it needs to be in order to check whether the input data is being sent properly to the server (Because as mentioned in the question `$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];` gives nothing). Next the formData() method could be used to send the data if the `serializeArray()`  is working. Also, old browsers does not support the formData() method.

Comment: Lol formData is not only for file types. You need to get your facts straight..  Also OP never mentioned that he uses an old browser... You need some tutorials though